# Neo4j cypher query improvement (performance)

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I have the following cypher query:

```
CALL apoc.index.nodes('node_auto_index','pref_label:(Foo)')
YIELD node, weight 
WHERE node.corpus = 'my_corpus'
WITH node, weight 
MATCH (selected:ontoterm{corpus:'my_corpus'})-[:spotted_in]->(:WEBSITE)<-[:spotted_in]-(node:ontoterm{corpus:'my_corpus'}) 
WHERE selected.uri = 'http://uri1' 
      OR selected.uri = 'http://uri2' 
      OR selected.uri = 'http://uri3' 
RETURN DISTINCT node, weight 
ORDER BY weight DESC LIMIT 10
```

The first part (until the WITH) runs very fast (Lucene legacy index) and returns ~100 nodes. The uri property is also unique (selected = 3 nodes) 
I have ~300 WEBSITE nodes. The execution time is 48749 ms.

Profile:
[image]

How can I restructure the query to improve performance? And why there are ~13.8 Mio rows in the profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem was in the WITH clause which expanded the results enormous. InverseFalcon's answer makes the query faster: 49 -> 18 sec (but still not fast enough). To avoid the enormous expand I collected the websites. The following query takes 60ms

```
MATCH (selected:ontoterm)-[:spotted_in]->(w:WEBSITE)
WHERE selected.uri in ['http://avgl.net/carbon_terms/Faser', 'http://avgl.net/carbon_terms/Carbon', 'http://avgl.net/carbon_terms/Leichtbau']
AND selected.corpus = 'carbon_terms'
with collect(distinct(w)) as websites
CALL apoc.index.nodes('node_auto_index','pref_label:(Fas OR Fas*)^10 OR pref_label_deco:(Fas OR Fas*)^3 OR alt_label:(Fa)^5') YIELD node, weight 
WHERE node.corpus = 'carbon_terms' AND node:ontoterm 
WITH websites, node, weight
match (node)-[:spotted_in]->(w:WEBSITE)
where w in websites
return node, weight
ORDER BY weight  DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any occurrence of NodeUniqueIndexSeek in your plan, so the `selected` node isn't being looked up efficiently.

Make sure you have a unique constraint on :ontoterm(uri).

After the unique constraint is up, give this a try:

```
PROFILE CALL apoc.index.nodes('node_auto_index','pref_label:(Foo)')
YIELD node, weight 
WHERE node.corpus = 'my_corpus' AND node:ontoterm
WITH node, weight 
MATCH (selected:ontoterm)
WHERE selected.uri in ['http://uri1', 'http://uri2', 'http://uri3']
AND selected.corpus = 'my_corpus'
WITH node, weight, selected
MATCH (selected)-[:spotted_in]->(:WEBSITE)<-[:spotted_in]-(node) 
RETURN DISTINCT node, weight 
ORDER BY weight DESC LIMIT 10
```

Take a look at the query plan. You should see a NodeUniqueIndexSeek somewhere in there, and hopefully you should see a drop in db hits.